# SImple Ajax Jquery with php & mysql query

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

i look this tutorial
http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/
but i don't understand how to make this work with php file with sql, echo ""; etc
If someone can explain, i try everything and nothing appears
Thanks :)

```
var default_content = "";

$(document).ready(function () {

    checkURL();
    $('ul li a').click(function (e) {

        checkURL(this.hash);

    });

    //filling in the default content
    default_content = $('#pagesContent').html();


    setInterval("checkURL()", 250);

});

var lasturl = "";

function checkURL(hash) {
    if (!hash) hash = window.location.hash;

    if (hash != lasturl) {
        lasturl = hash;

        // FIX - if we've used the history buttons to return to the homepage,
        // fill the pageContent with the default_content

        if (hash == "")
            $('#pagesContent').html(default_content);

        else
            loadPage(hash);
    }
}


function loadPage(url) {
    url = url.replace('#page', '');

    $('#loading').css('visibility', 'visible');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php",
        data: 'page=' + url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            if (parseInt(data) != 0) {
                $('#pagesContent').html(data);
                $('#loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            }
        }
    });

}
```

load_page.php

```
<?php
if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");
$page = (int)$_POST['page'];
if(file_exists('pages/page_'.$page.'.php'))
echo file_get_contents('pages/page_'.$page.'.php');
else echo 'There is no such page!';
?>
```

demo.html

```
< a href="#page1">Page1< /a>
< a href="#page2">Page2< /a>
< a href="#page3">Page3< /a>
< a href="#page4">Page4< /a>
<div id="pageContent">
   //loaded ajax page
</div>
```

in this scenario , link  > index.html#page1 will load file 'pages/page_1.php'
but in main index.html  just can load html code , not php syntax .
Can I use php command in this case ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the problem here is that in the tutorials example, they simply use an HTML file. For this, `file_get_contents()` will work fine. However if you want your server to parse PHP code before serving it to the user, you should use the [`include()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

> [From the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) :
>
> The include statement **includes and evaluates** the specified file.

The [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function behaves silghtly differently :

> **`file_get_contents`** — Reads entire file into a string

It simply reads the contents of the file, the PHP code is not evaluated/executed/interpreted...